# JavaScript Regex: Inject specific number at specific position in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var s = '-10px -10px';
var n = '33px';
```

I need a regexp that produces this result: `'-10px 33px'`

Something like: `s.replace(???, n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to replace only a `-10` at the end of a string, you could do this:

```
s = s.replace(/-10px$/, n);
```

If you want to be able to replace *any* number, then you can use `\d` instead:

```
/-?\d+px$/
```

Answer (score 2):

How about not using any regex?

```
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")) + " " + n
```

Comment: Regex is shorter and more readable (for those who can read regex)

Comment: Shorter, yes... more readable? Well, like you said, it really depends. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like :

```
function repl(s, n, p) {
    var arr=s.split(/ /);
    arr[p] = n;
    return arr.join(' ');
}
```

and use it as :

```
var new = repl('-10px -10px', '33px', 1);
```

this will replace the second `-10px` with `33px`